# How to block traffic to a Kubernetes pod without using network policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I want to momentarily disconnect the connection to couchbase pod running inside aws. AWS does not support network policies by default because of this I cannot use the network policies. I tried modifying the route inside the pod using route command I am getting operation not permitted for this. Is there a way to block the traffic to a pod using some other mechanism?

Comment: is couch base to be disconnected from all other pods ? then u can simply scale down its replicas to 0, in otherwise case we can discuss

Comment: I do not want to scale down the cocuhbase. I just need to disrupt the connection to it

Comment: How did you setup your cluster? Are you using EKS or a self managed cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can temporary delete your service couchbase service object, then apply it again...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Istio its got a bunch of features you will likely need at some point on your adventures.

https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/service-entry/